# Trying to return an iterator with nested struct gives "does not name type" error

Tags: c++, stl

I'm defining a vector of a private struct inside a class, then trying to get a private function of that class to return an iterator. Simplified code:

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
private:
    struct B {
        ...
    };
    std::vector<B> vecB;
    typedef std::vector<B>::iterator BIter;

    BIter FindSomething();
};

BIter A::FindSomething() { ... }
```

Unfortunately, when i try and compile this I get the error: `'BIter' does not name a type`
on the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line should be

```
A::BIter A::FindSomething() { ... }
```

The reason is that `BIter` is internal to the `A` class, and when the compiler gets to the definition of `BIter A::FindSomething`, the context (the `A` class) has not been established for the return type, so you must fully qualify it.